# Transplanting Debian HDD From 32-bit > 64-bit Notebook

Tags: debian, migration, apt-get, 32-vs-64-bit

Okay so my old 32-bit notebook got old and died.
I preserved the old HDD (with bootable Debian OS).
I bought a newer 64-bit notebook and gave it the old HDD.
It worked perfectly for a long time and continues to do so.
The issue I'm having is with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`:

```
user@Debian:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.14) but 2.19-18 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.13-38+deb7u8) but 2.19-18 is installed
 libc6-i686 : PreDepends: libc6 (= 2.13-38+deb7u8) but 2.19-18 is installed
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.19) but 2.13-38+deb7u8 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Running `sudo apt-get -f install` returns similar errors.
I feel like these errors must stem from the change in architecture.
How can I specify to use *i386* or *amd64* packages instead of *i686?*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problems are a result of your notebook change. You still have a i386 Debian on an 64bit notebook - which is ok. There should be no problems because of this.

Your only problem is that you are upgrading from wheezy to jessie and some dependencies don't resolve. That happens and it is no big problem.

Remove those few offending packages, then upgrade. If you really need them, install them later again.

`libc-dev-bin` and `libc6-dev` are development binaries, libraries and header files. You need them to compile packages, you certainly don't need them during the upgrade.

`locales` will probably upgrade without problems once you removed the others.

`libc6-i686` is not another architecture - it is a part of the i386, but these libraries are optimized for i686 machines. You can remove them without problems.

So remove `libc-dev-bin`,`libc6-dev` and `libc6-i686` and try to upgrade again - it should probably work.

Comment: This is the type of answer I was looking for. How would you recommend removing the offending files?

Comment: Also what do you mean _i686_ is not another architecture? It's a completely different chip as far as I'm aware. I never really understood these designations in terms of software.

Comment: Remove those files using `sudo apt-get remove libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libc6-i686` If some other packages depend on them (perhaps another `-dev`-Package) remove them too. Then upgrade `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: An i686 is an 6th generation processor of the [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) family. It is a 32bit processor, so if you want to use it with Debian, you have to use Debian i386 architecture. They just had a special version of libc optimized for i686 processors.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` will always download the correct version for your installed OS. You can’t upgrade from 32-bit to 64-bit, you need to do a clean install. Backup your `/home` folder and do a clean install then copy your `/home` folder back.

Comment: Indeed, but going from 32-bit to 64-bit would also require reinstalling apps as well. A well maintained and operated system will keep all critical data in the users home directory... I assume this is a single user system so most other data would not be very relevant, just annoying to set back up.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas said, the upgrade issues aren't related to your notebook change (although I would personally choose to [crossgrade](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossGrading), that's for people who are comfortable with debian administration).

You can deal with upgrade errors by switching to aptitude.  aptitude will come up with many solutions to safely upgrade.  Replace apt-get invocations with aptitude ones:

```
sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
```

If the first solution removes many packages, type n to skip it, until you find one that only removes a handful of -dev packages.